# Run Visual Studio 2019 with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, visual-studio-2019

Hope you can help me. I am struggling with debugging a XSLT-stylesheet with MS Visual Studio 2019. Everything worked fine till I tried to use the "tokenize"-function. When trying to debug MS VS throws an exception "tokenize() is not a known XSLT-Function". Doing a little research I found tokenize is part of XSLT 2.0, but older versons MS VS can only handle XSLT 1.0. This shouldn't be a problem as I am using MS VS 2019. But maybe my XSLT-header is set up incorrectly. 
I would appreciate any hints, how to make my XSLT-stylesheet run with MS VS 2019.

An example is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:variable name="testVariable" select="tokenize(@compositeAttribute, ' ')"/>   
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that Microsoft Visual Studio supports XSLT 2? All Microsoft XSLT implementations (MSXML, XslTransform, XslCompiledTransform) are XSLT 1.0 processors. For the .NET platform, to run XSLT 2 or since 2017 the current version XSLT 3 you can use Saxon .NET HE from NuGet or https://saxon.sourceforge.net/. Saxon 9 is also available for Java and C/C++, even with PHP or Python bindings these days.

Comment: Great thanks. I was assuming XSLT 2 would work in the most recent version as all comments that VS support just XSLT 1.0 reffered to VS 2009 or 2010 ...Maybe I was obvious from then on :-)